# have bug with aeroo reports in openerp version 6.1

Tags: python, odoo

I got the following Error after I hit the print button, the report was full functional in openerp6.1 with aeroo:

Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report.
unexpected EOF while parsing in expression "__filter(get_label("report.account.account.balance","chart_account_id")" of "replace" directive (, line 1) (, line 1)
unexpected EOF while parsing in expression "__filter(get_label("report.account.account.balance","chart_account_id")" of "replace" directive (, line 1) (, line 1)
For more reference inspect error logs.

(, Exception(u'Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report.', TemplateSyntaxError('unexpected EOF while parsing in expression "__filter(get_label("report.account.account.balance","chart_account_id")" of "replace" directive (, line 1) (, line 1)',), 'unexpected EOF while parsing in expression "__filter(get_label("report.account.account.balance","chart_account_id")" of "replace" directive (, line 1) (, line 1)', u'For more reference inspect error logs.'), )
Please help me..

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a product written in Python or are you coding something in Python.  If the latter, could you post the code that caused the above traceback?

Comment: Python code that i was written into openoffice under the menu Insert->fiels->others->function->input field->reference was:  <get_label("report.account.account.balance","chart_of _account_id")

Answer (score 0):

All it means is the directive shown has a syntax error.  If you look at it it is fairly clear.   One set of parentheses is not closed.  The other common cause is missing the closing > tag